# Validate regex for PrimeFaces Password

Tags: regex, jsf, primefaces

I have password and repeat password fields,But I want to validate passwords depending on validate regex pattern along with matching both the password fields too.

```
           <p:outputLabel for="Password" value="Password" />
                <p:password id="Password" redisplay="true"
                    value="#{newUserBean.newUserDTO.password}" match="RepeatPassword"
                    label="Password" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Password is required, cannot be empty"
                    validatorMessage="Password and Repeat Password fields must be same" feedback="true"
                    promptLabel="Password should contain atleast 8 characters ,1 number and 1 special character" >
                </p:password>
                <p:outputLabel for="RepeatPassword" value="Repeat Password" />
                <p:password id="RepeatPassword" redisplay="true"
                    value="#{newUserBean.newUserDTO.password}" label="RepeatPassword"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Password is required, cannot be empty" feedback="true"
                    promptLabel="Repeat Password should match with Password">
                </p:password>
```

Comment: Is the code executed on the server, or the client side?

Comment: It for registration form, It is on client side only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes as below

```
<p:outputLabel for="Password" value="Password" />
                <p:password id="Password" redisplay="true"
                    value="#{newUserBean.newUserDTO.password}"validator="#{passwordValidator.validate}"
                    label="Password" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Password is required, cannot be empty"
                    validatorMessage="Password and Repeat Password fields must be same" feedback="true"
                    promptLabel="Password should contain atleast 8 characters ,1 number and 1 special character" >
<p:ajax event="blur" update="msgfrpassword" />
                </p:password>
                <p:outputLabel for="RepeatPassword" value="Repeat Password" />
                <p:password id="RepeatPassword" redisplay="true"
                    value="#{newUserBean.newUserDTO.password}" label="RepeatPassword" validator="#{confirmPasswordValidator.validate}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Password is required, cannot be empty" feedback="true"
                    promptLabel="Repeat Password should match with Password">
<p:ajax event="blur" update="msgfrpassword" />
                </p:password>
```

Override java validator to verify regex and compare repeat password and password

### PasswordValidatorBean

```
@Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
        if (!matcher.matches()) {

            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                    new MessageProvider()
                            .getValue("prometheus_passwordpromptlable"));
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you need a regex to be both suitable for running on server and client side, I can suggest this regex that

- checks the password length - `.{8,}`
- makes sure there is at least 1 digit - `(?=.*[0-9].*$)`
- and 1 special character (please define what special character means for you, add or remove accordingly) - `(?=.*[-+()[\]~!@#$%^&*+}{":;'/?.><,`\].*$)`

Regex:

```
^(?=.*[-+()[\]~!@#$%^&*+}{":;'/?.><,`\\].*$)(?=.*[0-9].*$).{8,}$
```

Comment: i know that, I TRIED IT BY BELOW PATTERN. but I am facing problem to seperate two cases 1. Depending on validate regax and 2. depending on matching both passwords. I want to impose both validators.
 <f:validateRegex
      pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:;'?/&gt;.&lt;,])(?!.*\s).*$" />